# Squid proxy: how to use ipv6 address to send requests

Tags: proxy, ipv6, squid

I have installed `Squid` in one digital ocean ubuntu machine.

What I want to do is:  I will send a `ipv4` address to this proxy server and I need to pick up and use a `iPv6` address configured in the `squid.conf`. 
I have added 2 `ipv6` addresses in the conf file.

If I try the following command by specifying address as ipv6, it works fine.

```
curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --proxy localhost:3128 [2400:xxx:x:xx::xxx:a001]
```

ie, it will pick a random `ipv6` address from the conf file and send the request through that ip address.

If i try the following command by specifying address as ipv4, its not working

```
curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --proxy localhost:3128 34.xxx.xxx.148
```

ie, Its not picking the ipv6 address specified in the conf file. Instead  its using the server public ip .

My `/etc/squid/squid.conf` file content is something like this now.

```
acl one_fourth_3 random 1/2
acl one_fourth_4 random 1/1
tcp_outgoing_address 2604:xxxx:xxx:xxx::xx:a001 one_fourth_3
tcp_outgoing_address 2604:xxxx:xxx:xxx::xx:a002 one_fourth_4

http_access deny !safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow all
http_access deny all
http_port 3128
```

My squid version is

```
Squid Cache: Version 3.5.12
Service Name: squid
```

Answer (score 0):

Squid implicitly use the IP version, you should use or force IPv6.

Squid will add an implicit IP version test to each line.

Requests going to IPv4 websites will use the outgoing 10.1.0.* addresses.

Requests going to IPv6 websites will use the outgoing 2001:db8:* addresses.

http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/tcp_outgoing_address/